# WordPress menu item float right and vertical align issue

Tags: ios, css, wordpress, css-float, vertical-alignment

I am hoping one of you CSS gurus can help me pinpoint why my code isn't working!  Here's my site:

http://ledvideowall.net

When the browser window is > 600 pixels, the "CALL US" menu item is floating right and vertically centered in the menu bar.  (on FireFox and Chrome)

But, when the browser < 600 pixels, the menu item no longer floats right.  And, on Chrome and iOS devices, the menu item is placed vertically below the menu bar. (very difficult to see!)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `width:100%` to `.nav-menu` in css file.

Comment: thanks - it needed to be added to the media query section of the CSS!

Answer (score 0):

Well I am not getting this issue. However,

You should not be including that in the same `ul`. Instead, you should make a separate `div` and float that to the right (`float:right;`), and put the actual menu separately floated to the left (`float:left;`).

p.s. **DO NOT** add `width: 100%` to `.nav-menu`. This only resolves a **symptom** not the **main problem**.